# Redis: add to array for certain length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to have an array in Redis (using Node) where I can add values to it and specify how long I want it to stay in there. After that time limit, they should be deleted, and ideally be able to call something so I know what just left. ex. I may get a request with 120s, so I want to add that value to a map for that long and then have it deleted.

Is there a better way to do this? I thought of using the EXPIRE but that seems to be just for keys, not elements in an array?

Any thoughts would be great.

This is what I am doing:

```
app.get('/session/:length', function(req, res) {
    var length = parseInt(req.param('length'), 10);

    addToArray(length, ip)
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

    res.json({ip: ip, length: length});
```

});

Basically, I when I add it to the array I want it to only keep it in the array for the time that is passed in. So if you say 30 seconds, it's in that array for 30s, and then is gone, and calls a callback. Maybe there is a better way to solve this problem?

What I do now is keep the times added and ip, time in an array and periodically loop through the array checking and deleting, but thought maybe it would be possible in redis to automatically do this.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do? Maybe what you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't an automatic way to do that in Redis, the common approach to these kind of problems is to use a Redis sorted set. In your case, set the IP as the member's value and the expiry time (now + time to live) as the score using epoch representation.

Instead of looping periodically, you can just call [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) every once in a while.

Since set members are unique, however, that means that you'll only be able to save each IP once. If that's OK, just update the score for an IP with every hit from it, otherwise make the member value unique by concatenating the IP with the timestamp.

Lastly, to get the IPs that haven't "expired", use ZRANGEBYSCORE to get members that have scores (expiry times) higher than now. Similarly and before deleting with ZREMRANGEBYSCORE, get the keys that expired for the callback logic that you mentioned.